# How to remove part of file name in R?

Tags: r, string, filenames, paste

I am using a function which produces pdf file. I use the following:

```
file.rename(from = paste0(temp_dir, "/ratios.xlsx"), 
                to = paste0(path, "/", format(Sys.time(), "%F"), 
                     "_", filename, " ", "RESULTS.xlsx"));
```

the filename contains _TST which I do not want to have.

> **How can I take _TST away from the name of file?**

Comment: Just replace "_TST" with an empty string: `gsub("_TST", "", filename)`. It would be easier to help if you gave values of these variables so we could test possible solutions.

Comment: [learn regEx here](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
gsub('_TST','', 'abcd_TST') 

Result:  "abcd"
```